# Maven Shade does not include "META-INF/versions" of multi-release dependency

Tags: maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin, multi-release-jar

In our project, we create a "skinny" jar, which only includes our own application code and we use maven shade plugin to create the JARs for the dependencies we need to run the application. Maven shade is used to package multiple dependencies into the same jar. For example all jetty dependencies are packaged into one bigger `jetty-full.jar`.
Now we are facing an issue with the `org.graalvm.js` dependency. It depends on `truffle-api` which itself is a multi-release jar and includes classes for java 11 under `META-INF/versions/11`. As we are using Java 11, we need those classes but for some reason they are excluded by the maven shade plugin.
Here is the code of the related `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>project-dependencies</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>graal-full</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <graalvm.version>21.3.0</graalvm.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
      <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer
                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The `META-INF` of the resulting jar only contains the following folders and files:

- upgrade
- services
- native-image
- maven
- MANIFEST.MF (File)

The `versions` folder is missing.
I am now using `copy-dependency` plugin instead to copy the single files and there the `META-INF` contains `versions/11` folder with the needed Java 11 class.
Am I missing something or why is the `META-INF/versions` excluded from the shaded jar?

Comment: There is no resource transformer available which supports multi release jar... you might need to write your own...

Comment: So the resource-transformer is the problem here? Is there a "copy-as-is" resource transformer which I could use?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be something of a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713830/516433), and it appears that you can set `Multi-Release`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>foo.bar.Generate</Main-Class>
              <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Even though [it is not documented](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-385?focusedCommentId=17567674&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17567674)